# Prove the following coordinates are the coordinates of a rectange

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

The coordinates are (1,0,1) (0,2,0)(1,4,3) and (2,2,4).
Do you start by working out equations of the diagonal between two points each and then show the diagonals intersect at the same point?

Comment: 1. Find the midpoints of the two diagonals. If they coincide, that figure is at least a parallelogram. 2. Use that point as center (O) and radius = OA to form s sphere. If B, C, D all lie on that sphere, ABCD is a rectangle.

Comment: so when you find the midpoints of the two diagonals, they turn out to be (1,2,2) for both diagonals

Comment: I'm not sure how to mathematically write this out though?

Comment: Referring to your first comment:- that figure is at least a parallelogram.  It could be a rectangle depending on whether condition #2 is also true or not.

Comment: If O = (p, q, r), then the equation of the sphere is $(x - p)^2 + (y - q)^2 + (z - r)^2 = OA^2$. Test whether B, C, D satisfy that equation or not.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. so the centre would be (1,2,2)

Comment: Good. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

If :
$$A=(1,0,1) \quad B=(0,2,0) \quad C=(1,4,3) \quad D=(2,2,4)
$$

than the sides of the quadrilateral can be represented by vectors
$$
\overline{AB}=A-B=(1,-2,1) \quad\overline{CB}=(1,2,3) \quad \overline{DC}=(1,-2,1) \quad\overline {DA}=(1,2,3)
$$
and the inner product of two consecutive sides is
$$
\overline{AB}\cdot \overline{CB}=0
$$
what can be deduced?